# Grouping of columns with comma separated and padding extra blanks in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

I have a table with similar data as below

```
Label   Value   ColorCode
--------------------------
M1      0.5     #C71585
M1      1.5     #808080
M2      1       #C71585
M2      2       #C71585
M2      1.6     #FFC0CB
M3      3       #9400D3
```

I want the data to be converted as below:

```
Label   Data
-------------------------------------------
M1      0.5,"#C71585",1.5,"#808080","",""
M2      1,"#C71585",2,"#C71585",1.6,"#FFC0CB"
M3      3,"#9400D3","","","",""
```

**Explanation**: For each Label , I need to count the no of values in the table and pick the highest count.In this example , it is for M2 with count 3.

Now I have to append value and ColorCode columns with comma separated based on label. That part I have already done. The problem here is I need to be able to append the extra ""(double quotes) for which the count is less.

Example, for M1 , the count is 2(which is 1 less than the max count), So I have to append 1*2 "" in order to match with my max count label(M2). Similarly for M3, the count is 1(which is 2 less than the max count), so I have to append 2*2 "" (double quotes) to match with M2.

This is the query I have written to get the comma separated data.

```
SELECT
    T1.Label,
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(T.Value AS VARCHAR) + ',"' + T.ColorCODE + '"'
           FROM Table1 T        
           WHERE T.Label = T.Label        
           ORDER BY T.Label
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS Data
FROM Table1 T1 
GROUP BY T1.Label
ORDER BY T1.Label
```

Can any one tell me how to append the extra double quotes as explained above.
Thanks a lot in advance!!

PS: I'm using SQL Server 2014 Express Edition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Replicate`. I just edited a bit your query

```
SELECT
    T1.Label
    , STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + CAST(T.Value AS VARCHAR) + ',"' + T.ColorCODE + '"'
        FROM Table1 T       
        WHERE T.Label = T1.Label       
        ORDER BY T.Label
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'') + replicate(',"",""', max(count(*)) over () - count(*)) AS Data
FROM Table1 T1    
GROUP BY T1.Label
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
SELECT
    T1.Label
    , STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + CAST(T.Value AS VARCHAR) + ',"' + T.ColorCODE + '"'
        FROM @Table T       
        WHERE T.Label = T1.Label       
        ORDER BY T.Label
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,'') AS Data
FROM @Table T1    
GROUP BY T1.Label
ORDER BY T1.Label
```

[image: Output]

Comment: This is very close to what the user have asked. Since the `M2` has the most number of values, therefore the other `Label` must have the same number of values too and when it is empty, it must have added with ***empty*** values.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. But I also need to append extra "" too.How can I achieve this

Comment: @CrazyCoder, so you need number of values in data in each row to be same??

Comment: @sanatsathyan Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative solution for you !---

**Create Data**

```
CREATE TABLE TestC
(
     Label VARCHAR(10)
    ,Value   DECIMAL(10,2)
    ,ColorCode VARCHAR(20)
)
GO

INSERT INTO TestC VALUES
('M1',0.5,'#C71585'),
('M1',1.5,'#808080'),
('M2',1  ,'#C71585'),
('M2',2  ,'#C71585'),
('M2',1.6,'#FFC0CB'),
('M3',3  ,'#9400D3')
GO
```

**SOLUTION**

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT  Label ,  MAX(COUNT(*)) OVER() - COUNT(*) c  FROM TestC
    GROUP BY Label
)
,CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT Label , CONCAT ( Value , ',"' , ColorCode , '"') Vals
    FROM TestC 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.Label , '""' Vals FROM CTE1 c
    INNER JOIN master..spt_values m  ON c.c >= m.number 
    WHERE m.type = 'p' AND c.c > 0
)
SELECT c.Label , 
        STUFF((
        SELECT ',' + Vals
        FROM CTE2 c1      
        WHERE c1.Label = c.Label       
        ORDER BY c1.Label
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1,1,'') cData
FROM CTE2 c 
GROUP BY c.Label
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Label      cData
---------- ---------------------------------------------------------
M1         0.50,"#C71585",1.50,"#808080","",""
M2         1.00,"#C71585",2.00,"#C71585",1.60,"#FFC0CB"
M3         3.00,"#9400D3","","",""

(3 rows affected)
```